# Hyper-V, BitLocker usage both on the virtualized system and the drive of the host system

Tags: windows, hyper-v, windows-10, bitlocker

Using Hyper-V on a Windows 10 Pro computer, all Hyper-V VM related data is stored on a non-system secondary SSD: `D:\`.

I know that you can use BitLocker in the VMs themselves, by enabling TPM support in the VM, and then enabling BitLocker encryption on the desired drives in the virtualized OS.

Is there any problem to use BitLocker from the host OS to encrypt the drive that stores the VMs data? (in my case `D:\`), whether I use or not BitLocker on the VMs themselves (as described above).

*Note: In my case, VM usage is mostly for testing purposes, but I'm also interrested in a more general answer, with possibly a discussion of the overall pros and cons of the single (host level only) or double (both on the host level and the virtualized OS level) use of BitLocker protection.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no problem to be expected.
If you setup d: to automatically unlock, you may even leave machines running during reboot of your host.